# How to find the biggest number in permutation in O(1) time and space complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have non-negative integer N and I need to find the largest number in the permutation of N.

For example, given `N = 213` the function should return `321`.

How to do this in `O(1)` time and space complexity?

N is an integer within the range [0...2,147,483,647]

If the result exceeds `100 000 000` we can return `-1`

Comment: Surely this can't be done in `O(1)` if you allow for an arbitrary-length numbers.

Comment: N is an integer within the range [0...2,147,483,647]

Comment: It is in `O(log(N))` or maybe `O(log(N) * log(log(N)))`. For practical purposes that is `O(1)` and with a limited range anything is `O(1)` anyways.

Comment: In that case it could be done in O(1) time since the length is limited. Just count the number of nines, eights and so on and then put them in that order. A twist would be of course if the answer has to be in that range too.

Comment: @skyking That is a very good point. Counting sort will do it in O(1).

Comment: Are you looking for the greatest number or `uint32` (which is limited) ?

Comment: @skyking What makes you think that traversing the digits and counting each digit for an arbitrary length number is `O(1)`? That certainly sounds `O(N)`

Comment: As I said N is an integer within the range `[0...2,147,483,647]`. But function should return the largest number in the `family` of N.

Comment: @CoryKramer Because N is limited (always less than 11). O(N) means that it takes less than KN time and O(1) means that it takes less that L time for some constants K and L. Now N is less than 11 so if it takes less than KN time it would take less than L=11K time.

Comment: @skyking: if there is no variable size, there are no complexities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the number of times you have each digit, and then create a number that has the highest digits first, and then the next smaller digits etc.

Example: `N=234543`

```
2: 1 time
3: 2 times
4: 2 times
5: 1 time
```

Now make a number that has `5` once as the first digit, then `4` twice, `3` twice and `2` once - hence you get `544332`.

This is done in `O(Number of digits)` and not limited to the size of `int`. It could be any number (represented in a string or something similar).

This is a case of [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) where the number of different items is 10.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do it in `O(1)`, you must essentially sort the list of numbers highest to lowest, so the fastest you can do it is based on the complexity of your sort algorithm. You can see the time and space complexity of various sorting algorithms [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

[image]

Comment: Note that this is a very special case where the value set of the elements is very limited. You can sort that in O(N) time, N being the number of digits. Normally one would go for quicksort as the algorithm of choice, but not this time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limited number set, but large memory, you can create a hash for each number lol. E.g.:

A["213"] = 321

A["12"] = 21

etc.